# Evaluating this integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Dear stackexchange community,

I was wondering, I have a certain integral and I was a little unsure on the method of integration for it. The integral in question is:

$$
\int{dy}=\frac{1}{C}\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}+bx^{2}}}}
$$
Any tips on how to treat this integral would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We begin with the integral

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac ax+bx^2}}\,dx=\int \frac{x^{1/2}}{\sqrt{a+bx^3}}\,dx$$

Then, we enforce the substitution

$$u=b^{1/2}x^{3/2}+\sqrt{a+bx^3}$$

so that

$$\begin{align}
du&=\left(\frac32b^{1/2}x^{1/2}+\frac32\frac{bx^2}{\sqrt{a+bx^3}}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac32b^{1/2}\frac{x^{1/2}}{\sqrt{a+bx^3}}\left(\sqrt{a+bx^3}+b^{1/2}x^{3/2}\right)\,dx\\\\
\frac1u\,du&=\frac32b^{1/2}\frac{x^{1/2}}{\sqrt{a+bx^3}}\,dx
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac ax+bx^2}}\,dx&=\frac2{3b^{1/2}} \int\frac1u \,du\\\\
&=\frac{2}{3b^{1/2}}\log\left(b^{1/2}x^{3/2}+\sqrt{a+bx^3}\,\right)+C
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That's one of the wildest substitutions - I'd never think that leads to simplification - any leads to how to see that?

Comment: @orion A bit of engineering and tinkering.  First, I observed that the derivative of the denominator is $\frac{3bx^2}{2\sqrt{a+bx^3}}$ and the derivative of $x^{3/2}$ is $\frac32 x^{1/2}$.  Then, I noticed that $x^2=x^{3/2}x^{1/2}$.  Then, the construction began ...  I would like to see other approaches, and I am sure that there are.  - Mark